# When to use hasMany and belongsTo relations in Loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have one simple question about LoopBack 4 and relations.

Let's take for example the official TodoList example.

There is a `@hasMany` definition in `TodoList.model`, I have no questions there. My question is about the relation BelongsTo, is it also necessary to define `@belongsTo` in `todo.model`? Is it **always** necessary to define both relations or how can I know which one to choose? If just one relation is necessary, why are there two relataions to choose? What are the differences if I choose one over another?

Many doubts around this topic for me.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these relation types are although represent similar kind of relationship but have subtle differences from one another.

As we can see from the documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasMany-relation.html),

> A hasMany relation denotes a one-to-many connection of a model to
>   another model through referential integrity. The referential integrity
>   is enforced by a foreign key constraint on the target model which
>   usually references a primary key on the source model. This relation
>   indicates that each instance of the declaring or source model has zero
>   or more instances of the target model. For example, in an application
>   with customers and orders, a customer can have many orders

So, in case where you need to have a FK relationship 1:n, then you will use this. But, this will be used when the FK is on 'one' side. Meaning, customer (one) table will have orders (many) column as an array of FK with Order table.

As we can see from the documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/BelongsTo-relation.html),

> A belongsTo relation denotes a many-to-one connection of a model to
>   another model through referential integrity. The referential integrity
>   is enforced by a foreign key constraint on the source model which
>   usually references a primary key on the target model. This relation
>   indicates that each instance of the declaring or source model belongs
>   to exactly one instance of the target model. For example, in an
>   application with customers and orders, an order always belongs to
>   exactly one customer

So, in case where you need to have a FK relationship 1:n, then you will use this. But, this will be used when the FK is on 'many' side. Meaning, Order (many) table will have customer (one) column as an FK with Customer table. No need of array here.

Most of the time you will be using Belongs to relation for such cases though. That works in almost all the scenarios. I have not encountered any specific case to utilize hasMany yet.